# Redirect from query string to clean path in firebase

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-hosting

I changed the url structure of my website and i want to do 301 permanent redirect, but it doesn't seem to work, i want to redirect from example.com/?p=MJvb9ZO1y6Q to example.com/p/MJvb9ZO1y6Q.html

here's the redirects section in my firebase.json file

```
 "redirects": [{
  "regex": "/?p=(.*)",
  "destination": "/p/:1.html",
  "type": 301
}]
```